# How to manage the connection error of the socket io in react js project

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

Are there any way to handle the connection error of socket io?

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client"; 
import {ServerCon} from './Server'


export const socket = io(ServerCon.socketIo, { transports: ['websocket'] })
export const SocketContext = React.createContext();
```

in console show this error, but i want to catch the error and show a modal with a message
[image]